# Insert Massive data entries to DB using Restful/Queue/Java Concurrent/Global variable

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, global-variables

I want to read 1 million records from a file and send the record one at a time through a POST method using Restful API. I could have a DAO inside my POST and send it to a database, but performance wise I want to do a bulk upload. So right now I am thinking to using a BlockingQueue. The POST method will keep adding the records to the queue, and when the queue reaches 200 records each time, I will start a thread to bulk load the 200 to a database.

I have done/tested the POST method and sending data to a DB part. But I am stuck in the part of polling from a queue because somehow my queue is EMPTY! I think I might use the private static variable in the wrong way. Any insight please..

```
class MyRestful {
   MyQueueClass myQueue = new MyQueueClass();

   @POST
   @Path("/record")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response postRecord(MyRecord myRecord) {
       myQueue.add(myRecord);
       String result = "Record created: " + myRecord;
       return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
   }
}

class MyQueueClass implements Callable<T>{

    private static BlockingQueue<MyRecord> myRecordBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void add (MyRecord myRecord) {
        myRecordBlockingQueue.add(myRecord);
    }

    public List<MyRecord> outputDataBulk (BlockingQueue<MyRecord> myRecordList) {
        List<MyRecord> list = new ArrayList<>();
        myRecordList.drainTo(list, 200);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        List<MyRecord> list = outputDataBulk(myRecordBlockingQueue);
        System.out.println(myRecordBlockingQueue.size()); 
        // IT PRINTS OUT 0 HERE !
        ...
        //perform bulk upload to db here
    }

}

In my main, I will start multithreads to run the bulk uploading:

public static void main (String[] arg) {
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
   for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
      executor.submit(MyQueueClass());
   }
   ...
}
```

I am definitely doing something stupid here.. but how do I carry the record value that is posted in the POST method to the queue over.. that is my question.

Comment: When is `myQueue.call' called?

Comment: That code shows a serious misunderstanding how *basic* Java works.

Comment: Hi Rick, it will be called in main. I edited the question.

Comment: Hi Kayaman, could you be a little specific plz.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Did you copy paste parts from somewhere?

Comment: no, I did not...